# Access violation when freeing Indy SSLIOHandler

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

Delphi 11.3 - default Indy components that come with this Delphi version.

I have a DelphiMVCFramework REST API server using SSL.

In my client application, I use the `TRestClient` object from MVCFramework to connect to the REST API server. This `TRestClient` uses a standard `TIdHTTP` component.

Both server and client applications use the SSL libraries 1.0.2u downloaded from https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

The communication with the REST API server works perfectly.

I have a `BaseService` parent class that holds the `TRestClient` object. This is the getter of my `TRestClient` property:

```
function TBaseService<T>.GetRestClient: TRestClient;
var
  SSLIoHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  if not Assigned(FRestClient) then
  begin
    SSLIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    SSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [TIdSSLVersion.sslvSSLv23,
                                             TIdSSLVersion.sslvSSLv3,
                                             TIdSSLVersion.sslvTLSv1,
                                             TIdSSLVersion.sslvTLSv1_1,
                                             TIdSSLVersion.sslvTLSv1_2
                                             ];
    FRestClient := TRESTClient.Create(SERVER, PORT, SSLIOHandler);
  end;

  Result := FRestClient;
end;
```

And the destructor of the `TBaseService` class:

```
destructor TBaseService<T>.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FRestClient) then
      FRestClient.Free;
  
  inherited;
end;
```

This `TBaseService` class implements an `IBaseService` interface, and I create instances of derived `TBaseService` classes by using Spring4D.

When using transient instances, there is no problem when the instances are being freed.

I do have 1 singleton instance, which is freed when the application is shut down.

When that happens, the freeing of the `TRestClient` gives an Access Violation in the destructor of `TIdSSLSocket` (when `ssl_shutdown` is called).

Any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: The actual error would help.

Comment: You never need to check `Assigned()` before calling `Free()`, as it internally handles a `nil` object reference for you.  That being said, this is hardly a [mcve] to demonstrate the error in action. But my gut feeling is that some earlier action prior to the destructor being called has instructed Indy to unload OpenSSL from memory prematurely, thus resetting the `ssl_shutdown` function pointer back to `nil`, hence the AV (does the error message say the AV occurs at memory address 0?). This would imply a logic bug somewhere in your code that is not managing Indy objects correctly.